# Using the Slack web API when deep linking to direct message/IM, I get "#deleted-channel"

Tags: slack-api

When responding to a slash command with a string that includes a channel ID like `<#C3989289>`, the response in Slack shows a deep link to that channel "#general.

When I do the same for a direct message or IM, the response in Slack shows "#deleted-channel" and it's not a link.

I don't see anything in the docs about why this:  https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#linking_to_channels_and_users

Answer (score 1):

Slack has confirmed that their system is designed in this way to protect private channels/direct messages from being made aware to users, even if the recipient of the message containing the deep link *does* belong to that particular channel/DM.